# Flutter Firebase phone authentication code not sending via SMS

Tags: swift, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, apple-push-notifications

Im trying to enable Firebase Phone Authentication in my flutter project so it actual sends an SMS with an authentication code to the entered number.

-Uploaded the APNs Authentication Key into the Firebase project settings under "Cloud Messaging"

-I also added:

```
io.flutter.embedded_views_preview
<string>NO</string>
```

to the info.plist file

Then I activated Background modes -> Remote Notifications and Push Notifications in the Xcode project and implemented these two functions in the AppDelegate.swift file:

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) 
{
    // Pass device token to auth
        Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: 
AuthAPNSTokenType.prod)

    // Further handling of the device token if needed by the app
    // ...
  }

  override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
      didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : 
Any],
      fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping 
(UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)
      return
    }
    // This notification is not auth related, developer should 
handle it.
  }
```

---

This is the code that handles the whole phone authentication process in the Login Screen

```
Future<void> verifyPhone() async {
final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verID) {
  this.verificationID = verID;
};

final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verID, [int 
forceCodeResend]) {

  this.verificationID = verID;
  smsCodeDialog(context).then((value) {
  });
};

final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationSuccess =
    (AuthCredential credential) {
};

final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
    (AuthException exception) {
  print("verification failed this bullshit");
  if (exception.message.contains('not authorized'))
    print(
        'Something weird has gone really wrong, please do not try 
later');
  else if (exception.message.contains('Network'))
    print('Please check your internet connection and try again');
  else if (exception.message.contains("credential is invalid"))
    print("credential is invalid you jerk");
  else
    print('Something has gone horribly wrong, please try later or 
never -> ${exception.message}');
};

await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: "+" + dialingCode + this.phoneNo,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    verificationCompleted: verificationSuccess,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: smsCodeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve);
}


  signIn() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = 
PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationID,
      smsCode: smsCode,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user = await 
_auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "root");
  }
```

When I enter my phone number and press on "send SMS" on a physical iPhone X, I expect to receive an SMS with the authentication key but instead get these errors:

```
The UIApplicationDelegate must handle remote notification for phone 
number authentication to work.

If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received 
by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth s 
canHandleNotificaton: method.
```

Comment: What happens? What are the errors? Also, can you send one using vanilla ios or Android code without Flutter? SMS sends have a lot of moving parts and isolating the problem to a specific lib or tool, and then surfacing a meaningful error will be the first steps to success here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using a version of `firebase_auth` that come with that issue, you can check info about that in this [flutter issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35267)

The solution for me was to add this fork of `firebase_auth`:

```
firebase_auth:
git:
  url: https://github.com/collinjackson/plugins.git
  ref: 441417c2fed0ff26bf84a49ab2c5ffd2aa5487de
  path: packages/firebase_auth
```

Or proabably you'll need to update your `firebase_auth` to version `0.11.1+8` to get the fix.

Hope this could help.